# nested table iteration error when using page-object gem

Tags: ruby, cucumber, page-object-gem

I'm trying to use PageObject gem and stuck on table iteration.
Here what I have:

**HTML**

```
<table id='list'>
  <tbody>
    <tr class='somename'>
      <td><a id='someid'><u>Edit</u></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='somename'>
      <td><a id='someid'><u>Edit</u></a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**PAGE_CLASS**

```
table(:my_table, id: 'list')
```

**STEP**

```
@current_page.my_table_element.each do |row|
  puts row.link_element(text: 'Edit')
end
```

---

**ERROR**

```
Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException: timed out after 30 seconds, waiting for {:id=>"list", :tag_name=>"table"} --> {:index=>0, :tag_name=>"tr"} --> {:text=>"Edit", :tag_name=>"a"} to be located
```

I see it is not passing tbody tag. Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: It would help if you provide the actual HTML you are working with. The sample HTML does not appear to reproduce the error. Given the error, I would guess that one of the rows, perhaps the column headings row, does not have an Edit link.

Comment: Thank you Justin Ko, this issue is solved by adding wait time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wait time solved this issue for me.